# Installing IsolationForest (Scikit-Learn) for Anaconda

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda

I'm trying to run IsolationForest on my installation of Anaconda, but it appears not to be contained within the Anaconda repo.

I have python 3.6 installed. I checked the library within the IDE to see if IsolationForest is contained within `ensembles`, and it is not. I tried `pip` and `conda update scikit-learn`. Also, I tried installing directly from git via `pip install git+git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn`, but received error messages.

This is what is returned when running `pip install git+git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn`:

```py
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install git+git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git
Collecting git+git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git
  Cloning git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git to c:\users\nick~1.tay\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-htpjngz7
  Running command git clone -q git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git 'C:\Users\NICK~1.TAY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-htpjngz7'
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.0 in c:\users\nick.taylor\.julia\conda\3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn==0.22.dev0) (1.17.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.17.0 in c:\users\nick.taylor\.julia\conda\3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn==0.22.dev0) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\users\nick.taylor\.julia\conda\3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-learn==0.22.dev0) (0.13.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: scikit-learn
  Building wheel for scikit-learn (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\nick.taylor\.julia\conda\3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\NICK~1.TAY\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-htpjngz7\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\NICK~1.TAY\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-htpjngz7\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\NICK~1.TAY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-4v2jdm2w' --python-tag cp36
       cwd: C:\Users\NICK~1.TAY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-htpjngz7\
  Complete output (28 lines):
  Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\NICK~1.TAY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-htpjngz7\setup.py", line 290, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "C:\Users\NICK~1.TAY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-htpjngz7\setup.py", line 286, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "C:\Users\nick.taylor\.julia\conda\3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 137, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "C:\Users\NICK~1.TAY\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-htpjngz7\setup.py", line 174, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('sklearn')
    File "C:\Users\nick.taylor\.julia\conda\3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1036, in add_subpackage
      caller_level = 2)
    File "C:\Users\nick.taylor\.julia\conda\3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1005, in get_subpackage
      caller_level = caller_level + 1)
    File "C:\Users\nick.taylor\.julia\conda\3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 942, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "sklearn\setup.py", line 67, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('utils')
    File "C:\Users\nick.taylor\.julia\conda\3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1036, in add_subpackage
      caller_level = 2)
    File "C:\Users\nick.taylor\.julia\conda\3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1005, in get_subpackage
      caller_level = caller_level + 1)
    File "C:\Users\nick.taylor\.julia\conda\3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 942, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "sklearn\utils\setup.py", line 8, in configuration
      from Cython import Tempita
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-learn
```

I expect to be able to install the latest full version of `sklearn` so I can make full use of the library.